conditional formatting EACH cell based on ANOTHER cell
I need to create a conditional formatting for several cells, each one of them based on another cell. E.g. B2 based on content of B3, C2 based on C3, etc. I know how to do it for one cell, but when I copy the format, the referenced cell is kept. E.g. if I create a conditional format for B2 based on content of B3, when I copy that format to C2, it keeps the rule based on B3, instead of C3. Is there a way to do this automatically? I need to apply it to hundreds of cells.

Suggestion
Though, it doesn't show that the criteria is being change, upon doing some test it is doing your expected result.
Sample GIF:

Note:
I cannot cite any reference with this answer, obviously there is some issues along with this and might be fluky in getting the right use case for you in the near future and depending on the complexity of your formula. Would you be open on getting an answer using Apps Script with more information about your expected result you can invoke the builder function that better satisfies your needs and will be more stable.
